# Jquery: listen for click on href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code, which I am unable to change:

```
<div id="stepbystep" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
      <a href="#step-1">
        <span>Step 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
      <a href="#step-2">
        <span>Step 2</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
      <a href="#step-3">
        <span>Step 3</span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I would like to use JQuery to listen for a click on one of the hrefs and pop up the href's destination.  This is the code I have so far, but I am getting the error `TypeError: $(...) is null`.  I think the problem is with my selector `$('div#stepbystep ul li a')`.

```
var tabCheck = {
  ready : function() {
    $('div#stepbystep ul li a').click(
      function($e) {
        $e.preventDefault();
        window.open(this, 'FavoriteLink', '');
        alert(this.href)
      }
    );
  }
};

$(document).ready(tabCheck.ready);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: [I'm not getting an error](http://jsfiddle.net/3X985/1/).

Comment: This works just fine? http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/fuYLX/1/  Perhaps you aren't including jQuery correctly?  If this is for wordpress you will have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: I'm using Joomla. Using `jQuery` instead of `$` has stopped the error, but the function isn't being triggered.  This is my latest code (simplified to just try to pop up 'hi':

`var tabCheck = {
  ready : function() {
    jQuery('div#stepbystep ul li a').click(
      function(e) {
        alert('hi');
      }
    );
  }
};

$(document).ready(tabCheck.ready);`

Comment: The above code works in jfiddle.  Is there anything else Joomla related that may be causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was using Joomla, so had to use `jQuery` instead of `$` as  Rob Schmuecker guessed in his comment.  I can't see a way to mark a comment as an answer, but thanks!

It still isn't working because the alert is not popping up, but I'll raise a different question for that.

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
 $('#stepbystep ul li a')
```

you don't need the '$' on $e either...

and maybe add a jsfiddle page?

Comment: i removed the **div**#stepbystep ul li a

Comment: That still produces the same functionality tho.